# Do elements that are nil in an Array automatically get deleted?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, null

```
    // MARK: - Reload Photos
    @IBAction func reloadCollectionView(sender: AnyObject) {
        var photosArray = annotation!.photos!
        if selecting {
            // Delete the photos from the photos array

            for path in selectedIndexPaths {
                print("selected path: \(path.row)")

                // Using inverse relationship to delete elements of array
                photosArray[path.row].customAnnotation = nil
            }

            print(photosArray.count)
            collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in
                self.collectionView?.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(self.selectedIndexPaths)
                }, completion: nil)
            selectedIndexPaths.removeAll()

        }
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource    
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(annotation?.photos!.count)
        return (annotation?.photos!.count)!
    }
```

Above is a simple implementation of a button that sets a element of the `photosArray` to nil if the index of that element is in the array of `selectedIndexPaths` it then deletes the selected `UICollectionViewCells` via the `DataSource`.

When I run program and say for example I selected 3 `UICollectionViewCells` out of the 21 that I have, and hence are added to my `selectedIndexPaths` array. I then press the `reloadCollectionView` button `print(photosArray.count)` would return `21` but then in `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection`, `print(annotation?.photos!.count)` magically returns `18`

I have tested in the playgrounds and I know that `nil` still counts as an element in an array, so I'm a bit confused as to what has happened. Is there something that the `DataSource` does in the background that automatically gets rid of `nil` elements? I'm quite confused, would anyone care to shed some light on this for me?

Comment: Is `photosArray` a dictionary?  What do you see if you Option-click on `photosArray`?

Comment: `photosArray` is an Array